# Unable to attach file to issue in jira via rest api Java

Tags: java, unirest, jira-rest-java-api

I want to attach multiple files to issue. I'm able to create issue successfully however i am facing problem in attaching documents after creating issue. I have referred to this link [SOLVED: attach a file using REST from scriptrunner](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Adaptavist-questions/SOLVED-attach-a-file-using-REST-from-scriptrunner/qaq-p/1107562)
 I am getting 404 error even though issue exists and also user has all the permissions.

```
File fileToUpload = new File("D:\\dummy.txt");
InputStream in = null;
try {
    in = new FileInputStream(fileToUpload);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

HttpResponse < String > response3 = Unirest
    .post("https://.../rest/api/2/issue/test-85/attachments")
    .basicAuth(username, password).field("file", in , "dummy.txt")
    .asString();
System.out.println(response3.getStatus());
```

here **test-85** is a issueKey value. 
And i am using **open-unirest-java-3.3.06.jar**.  Is the way i am attaching documents is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how open-unirest manages its fields, maybe it tries to put them as json field, rather than post content.

I've been using [Rcarz's Jira client](https://github.com/rcarz/jira-client). It's a little bit outdated but it still works.
Maybe looking at its code will help you, or you can just use it directly.
The Issue class:

```
public JSON addAttachment(File file) throws JiraException {
    try {
        return restclient.post(getRestUri(key) + "/attachments", file);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new JiraException("Failed add attachment to issue " + key, ex);
    }
}
```

And in RestClient class:

```
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;

public JSON post(String path, File file) throws RestException, IOException, URISyntaxException {
    return request(new HttpPost(buildURI(path)), file);
}

private JSON request(HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase req, File file) throws RestException, IOException {
    if (file != null) {
        File fileUpload = file;
        req.setHeader("X-Atlassian-Token", "nocheck");
        MultipartEntity ent = new MultipartEntity();
        ent.addPart("file", new FileBody(fileUpload));
        req.setEntity(ent);
    }
    return request(req);
}
```

So I'm not sure why you're getting a 404, Jira is sometime fuzzy and not really clear about its error, try printing the full error, or checking Jira's log if you can. Maybe it's just the `"X-Atlassian-Token", "nocheck"`, try adding it.

Comment: yes you are right!, i have missed X-Atlassian-Token. I was adding basic authorization instead of token.

Comment: @ariana777 and you were getting a 404 for this, it doesn't surprise me anymore from Jira but it still is weird ... good continuation ;)